# Get and set Spinner values

Tags: android, spinner

I am to android coding and have what I hope will be a simple question. I have an app that has a demographics page, with various spinners (although I will only use 1 for this example). The spinners are already populated, but the user can save them once they have made their choice so every time they open this app the previous choices are there.

My code to load the values into the spinner is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_demographics);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("data_file", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int ageValue = prefs.getInt("Age", 0);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    //set the default according to value
    spinner.setSelection(ageValue);
}
```

and then my code to save the data is

```
public void submitDemo(View view) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    int ageValue = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

    //save the current data from the spinner
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("data_file", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putInt("Age", ageValue);

    editor.commit(); 
    finish();
}
```

I'm not bothered about capturing the value when they change the spinner, just simply at the end. I know it's probably something simple that I'm missing, but if anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: how u are setting the Adapter for the spinner ?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?. i see you initializing spinner twice which is not necessary

Comment: I'm not setting an adapter for this. I did try but it didn't seem to make any difference. Obviously I could have been doing that wrong too. the problem is that it's not working, and that it crashes on both loading and clicking the submitDemo button

Comment: This is the code for the adaptor that I used previously. ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) spinner.getAdapter();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set an adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), 
   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_string_array));
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If `setSelection(value)` doesn't work try with

`spinner.setSelection(ageValue, true);`

This will "animate" the selection, i.e. scroll it to the selected position.

Comment: I tried this but still no luck. Should I be setting an adaptor (as commented above?)

Comment: Well, yes. Besides: are you sure you need a spinner? Wouldn't it be better if you use an `EditText`, validate the input and call `setError` if the format isn't right?

Comment: This is what I want to achieve. A demographics page (ie age, gender, etc etc) with predetermined choices (for the age say 18-25, 26-40 and so on). If there is a better way to do it then please feel free to suggest an alternative. As for the adaptor I used this line onCreate: ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) spinner.getAdapter();